# Proof of dimension equality

Tags: linear-algebra

Is my proof of $\mathrm{dim}(U+W)=\mathrm{dim}(U)+\mathrm{dim}(W)-\mathrm{dim}(U \cap W )$ correct?.Suppose we the basis of $U     \cap W$ is $B_{0}$ then we can add this basis to the basis of W let it be $B_{1}$ and to U let it be $B_{2}$.Then the basis of $U+W$ will be $B_{1}+B_{2}$. From this the conclusion follows.

Comment: this sum is not as the sum we know with numbers here the idea is If $U \cap W$ has basis $e_1...e_n$ then U will have basis for example $e_1...e_n...e_k$ and W will have basis $e_1...e_n..e_p$ for some k,p > n.Then $U+W $will have basis $e_1...e_n..e_k$ or $e_p$ dependint which is greater k or p

Comment: I assume the +1 and no comments as a correct proof guys :D

Answer (score 2):

To be blunt, all I see is: "[incomprehensible].  From this the conclusion follows."

If I were going to prove it, I would (and this is just a sketch):

- Let $B_U$ and $B_W$ be bases of $U$ and $W$, respectively, such that their intersection $B_U \cap B_W$ is of maximum size.
- Argue that $B_U \cup B_W$, which has size $|B_U|+|B_W|-|B_U \cap B_W|$, is a basis for $U+W$.

  (If it's not a basis, then ... contradiction.)

  Hence $\mathrm{dim}(U+W)=\mathrm{dim}(U)+\mathrm{dim}(W)-|B_U \cap B_W|$.
- Argue that $B_U \cap B_W$ is a basis for $U \cap W$.

  If it wasn't, then there's a vector $\mathbf{v} \in U \cap W$ not in the span of $B_U \cap B_W$.  Since $\mathbf{v} \in U \cap W$, we know $\mathbf{v}$ is a linear combination of vectors in $B_U$, and a linear combination of vectors in $B_W$.  Neither linear combination uses only basis vectors in $B_U \cap B_W$ (otherwise $\mathbf{v}$ would be in the span of $B_U \cap B_W$).  We can use this to construct bases for $U$ and $W$ with a larger intersection than $B_U \cap B_W$, giving a contradiction.

  Hence $\mathrm{dim}(U \cap W)=|B_U \cap B_W|$, completing the proof.

Comment: why don't you start with a basis of $U \cap W$ and extend to a basis for $U$ and $W?$

Comment: Yes like I do :D